# The rejection reason of my suggested edit is clearly nonsense

Tags: support, suggested-edits, rejected-edits, suggested-tags, reject-reasons

I suggested [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16791572) to improve [Clearinterval() doesn't animate the element position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45248027/clearinterval-doesnt-work-with-my-code-to-animate-element-position) 's display and relevence by:

- Changing a snippet that would never do anything (but `console.log` errors that had nothing to do with the question).
- Adding two relevant tags to aid search and categorization.

It was reviewed by [Dij](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4051713/dij) as "**reject**" because:

> This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner.

[image: reject reason on pending edit]

I don't check every reviewer's reaction to my efforts, but rather hope there's not too much of this kind of blatant nonsense going on, or my record is likely tainted by false negatives.

I think it plainly clear that (even if the edit wasn't the most important thing ever) my suggestions in no way deviated from the original's intent, and in fact does quite the opposite, as it better clarifies the intent.

As I post, the edit is still showing to me as "**pending**", so may still be accepted(?), but the review (I hope it is agreed) and thus the reviewer is in need of review.

**Are reviewers reviewed; will a moderator take a look at when else this reviewer has possibly made similar errors; is this process monitored?**

### Update

Edit approved by [Braiam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/792066/braiam).

Comment: Instead of calling out a specific user on Meta, you should have flagged the post for moderator attention and explained the issue.

Comment: @BSMP - Is that officially-documented-policy or opinion? My intent here is not to _"call out"_ any user(s); it would be impossible to provide all the relevant details without the reviewer being known. I am interested to know how to deal with obvious injustice, and whether it is routinely dealt with without specific intervention.

Comment: I would use the markdown diff instead https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0BWr.png

Comment: @Braiam - What does that image show that isn't already clear from my link or image?

Comment: Doesn't work is not a clear problem statement and there is no question asked. That means it is off-topic for the "Debugging / No MCVE" reason. If the edit does not make the question on-topic, it should not have been suggested, as such it should be rejected. This is a prime case of (for lack of a better term) turd-polishing. Your edits did nothing more than add polish to an otherwise off-topic post, in turn doing nothing more than wasting reviewers time.

Comment: Rereading my last comment I want to stress that your edits to that question _are polish_, it is what you're polishing that matters. There are much better questions to spend your time editing than that. But if you are going to edit questions like that, make sure that the question is on-topic after your edit.

Comment: related: [When should I make edits to code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260245/839601) (TL;DR: code is sacred cow, be _very_ careful when changing it)

Comment: @Braiam - I think I realise, after seeing Dan Lowe's answer below, what you meant by _"I would use the markdown diff"_; I wrongly thought you meant you would use it in the question. Yes it seems possible that the reviewer missed the change from snippet, but their reason for rejection still wouldn't make any sense.

Comment: @TinyGiant - You may be right that I was polishing a turd, but not purposefully. I don't think any one of us can be solely expected to get every thing right all the time, but should be expected to not do things wrong (too often). I don't think that not flagging the question as _"off topic"_ is reason to suggest the edit was bad. If the post is later flagged and removed , the edit bites the dust and there's no harm or foul. As I commented below _"perfect is the enemy of good"_ and not doing another thing is not reason to suggest that what I did do is wrong.

Comment: @TinyGiant - (cont. due to char restriction) - As for polishing in respect of bringing questions _"on topic"_, I have, and on two occasions (one post was removed I think) the same misunderstanding occurred. See [this rejection](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16671485) of a suggestion to narrow the broadness of a question flagged as _"too broad"_ and [this later acceptance](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16682092) doing basically the same thing. Unfortunately, due to the initial rejection, the post was possibly not pushed to the review queue the second time.

Comment: @gnat review the markdown diff. He doesn't edit code, nor anything that triggers meta radicalism.

Comment: @Braiam yeah I checked markdown diff prior to commenting, agree on that. However the fact that OP posted rendered diff here and didn't point in edit summary that their change needs to be reviewed with markdown suggests that they have no slightest idea of the norms of editing code over here. In the light of this fact their edit discussed here being non-breaking looks more like a pure luck

Comment: @gnat considering [that OP was pretty confused when I told him to use the markdown diff instead](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352657/#comment496052_352657) tells me that he probably didn't know better.

Comment: @gnat - I have _"no slightest idea"_ what it's like to review edit suggestions (yet), but know that I won't be relying on _"luck"_ when I do; I will take as much care to properly understand the question, and the edit as I currently take when suggesting edits. I would like to think that others with that privilege are encouraged to be as careful as me, and properly challenged if they prove to be doing otherwise.

Comment: I think you're trying your luck by not making any effort to help reviewers understand your edit better, especially with changes involving code. If I wanted my edit like that to pass through smoother I'd add to edit summary a note like "please review this change with markdown diff because rendered output diff makes it look like radical code change, which it really isn't"

Comment: Again @gnat "especially with changes involving code", there's no code involved. He has no idea that the reviewers would be so brain dead (they are, btw) that they can't figure out that the code didn't change in the slightness.

Comment: I don't pretend to be able to read the mind of anyone, much less 
 that of a reviewer. I explained why I would have rejected your edit. As for _"If the post is later flagged and removed ... no harm or foul"_, there _is_ foul because each reviewer gets a review limit of twenty tasks per day in that queue and there is a limit on the suggested edit queue that we have been hitting recently. This means each reviewer has spent one of their review tasks reviewing an ultimately pointless change, and your edit may have prevented another (possibly more valuable) edit from being suggested.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe this is simply reviewers looking at the rendered output and not viewing the markdown. I ran into this a number of times when I was still subject to edit reviews. Compare the two different views a reviewer might see.

First, there is the rendered output, which is the default view:

[image]

There is also the markdown:

[image]

If you only look at the first view, and don't carefully compare the code line by line, it looks like you replaced every single line of code. I could see that leading to the rejection that you're complaining about.

Looking at the markdown makes it clear that you didn't touch any code at all.

Unfortunately, a lot of reviewers seem to not bother looking at the markdown, or perhaps haven't noticed it's there.

The advice I got when I complained about similar reviews in the past was to make sure I mentioned what I had done in the edit summary. I see that you did that in this case, but another issue is reviewers sometimes don't bother reading edit summaries.

Comment: Thank you; this does look likely. I would hope that _"changed non functional snippet to plain code"_ should be understood as not meaning _"changed non functional code to functional code"_ (an obviously stupid thing to do), but I suppose I will try to make it more clear in future. Although this is meta and rep is basically irrelevant, I would like to mark this as answered for semantics; could you address the issue of what to do in the event of disagreeing with a decision?

Comment: @FredGandt if you disagree with the review, the process is "post on meta" which you have already done :)

Comment: It has been suggested in other comments that I should have flagged the question for moderator attention. I don't think that's what question flagging is for, but wonder what you think of that suggestion?

Comment: @FredGandt Views probably vary on that... I am personally very reluctant to use moderator flags, as I assume they get a lot of noise in their inbox here... so it really depends on the situation. For review disputes I have just posted on meta instead.

Answer (score 8):

Reviewers that fail review audits may get "reviewed" by moderators, otherwise - no, there is no additional review.

You can flag posts where you believe review was done wrong and moderators will take a look, also in this particular case I don't see rejection of "barely on-topic" to "barely on-topic with spelling fixed" edit to be invalid.

"No improvements whatsoever" could be better option... Code already looks fine, edit did not in any way mad post include more details (and instead spell-checked pointless "searched alot" sentence). Added tags are somewhat ok but again not adding much.

The edit would be fine have you waited 140 points and avoid review queue.

There is also likely duplicate "how to properly execute some code on timer" or "how to animate position" - finding one could be better use of your time than minor edit.

Comment: According to [these dos and don'ts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code/260246#260246), my edit should be considered constructive in all respects. Do you disagree with those pointers? Also consider that [Perfect is the enemy of good](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_is_the_enemy_of_good), and what I didn't do is not necessarily relevent.

Comment: @FredGandt and another victim of that faq. Use the help center instead.

Comment: The only constructive changes for me are wrapping "setinterval" in coding quotes and upper casing "My". The rest is more or less styling preference. I don't see removal of "code snippet" as significant improvement. If question would be nice and useful by itself - maybe edit is worth it, but for no-research/no real MCVE question... not really. Reviewed edits are expected to make post significantly better and not just change style a bit (again - would be perfectly fine edit if no review is needed as minor edits are ok in that case, also consider extra bumping to front page due to edits)

Comment: @Braiam - Like [this help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit), where it states pretty much the same things _i.e._ "to fix grammatical or spelling mistakes,
to clarify the meaning of a post without changing it,
to correct minor mistakes or add addendums / updates as the post ages,
to add related resources or hyperlinks"?

Comment: @FredGandt - yes, as soon as you hit 2K you are welcome to make such edit as help topic on privilege you've linked says. Suggested edits must be substantial (https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) - "are expected to be substantial and to leave the post better than you found it". I don't think the post can be edited to be substantially better as it is missing information that only OP can provide on why they think they code should have worked in the first place - so actual misunderstanding could be addressed rather than providing copy-paste ready code...

Comment: Thank you for improving your answer; are these _"audits"_ like those test reviews we get when reviewing triage and the like, or are they more hands on? Would a flag of a rejection I felt was wrong be potentially counted against me; if the mod agrees with the rejection, but my reason for asking for the decision to be reviewed is reasonable, would that flag be marked as _"helpful"_?

Comment: "Code already looks fine" use the markdown diff. The only changes was removing the codesnippet comments https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0BWr.png